# Springboot-Prometheus: Increment the http_server_requests_seconds_count counter only if it is from a particular source

Tags: java, rest, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have a Springboot project with prometheus and micrometer. When i check **http_server_requests_seconds_count**, I am getting the number of times a particular webservice is being called. But I want to increment the counter only when the webservice request is from a particular source alone. Any idea how to do this? 
Tried passing a querystring for a few calls alone. But the prometheus counter does not differentiates the count based on querystring it seems.

Comment: I would introduce a separate metric for this. And then increment it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server has a special hostname? if so you can increase it when receiving this specific name. Or maybe you have a certain function that handles this server's requests, if so you can look at the path and increase the metric only when getting /<correct_path>